# Resume Debezium MySQL connector after unexpected AWS RDS binlogs deletion

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

When Debezium is running as a source in kafka connect and if no updates happens for a while on that destination MySQL DB (Amazon RDS Instance), then after sometime I end up below error.

```
[2018-04-25 21:30:14,526] INFO Step 0: Get all known binlogs from MySQL (io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask:310)
[2018-04-25 21:30:14,536] INFO Connector requires binlog file 'mysql-bin-changelog.002640', but MySQL only has mysql-bin-changelog.002663, mysql-bin-changelog.002664, mysql-bin-changelog.002665 (io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask:323)
[2018-04-25 21:30:14,536] INFO MySQL has the binlog file 'mysql-bin-changelog.002640' required by the connector (io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask:325)
[2018-04-25 21:30:14,536] INFO Stopping MySQL connector task (io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask:239)
[2018-04-25 21:30:14,536] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=swiggy-connector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:328)
[2018-04-25 21:30:14,536] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=swiggy-connector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:345)
[2018-04-25 21:30:14,536] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=swiggy-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:172)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: The connector is trying to read binlog starting at binlog file 'mysql-bin-changelog.002640', pos=470, skipping 4 events plus 0 rows, but this is no longer available on the server. Reconfigure the connector to use a snapshot when needed.
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.start(MySqlConnectorTask.java:117)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:164)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I go to DB and check the binlogs in MySQL

```
mysql> show binary logs;
+----------------------------+-----------+
| Log_name                   | File_size |
+----------------------------+-----------+
| mysql-bin-changelog.002664 |       479 |
| mysql-bin-changelog.002665 |       120 |
+----------------------------+-----------+


mysql> show binlog events;
+----------------------------+-----+-------------+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Log_name                   | Pos | Event_type  | Server_id  | End_log_pos | Info                                                                                                                            |
+----------------------------+-----+-------------+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| mysql-bin-changelog.002664 |   4 | Format_desc | 1550192458 |         120 | Server ver: 5.6.39-log, Binlog ver: 4                                                                                           |
| mysql-bin-changelog.002664 | 120 | Query       | 1550192458 |         201 | BEGIN                                                                                                                           |
| mysql-bin-changelog.002664 | 201 | Query       | 1550192458 |         391 | use `mysql`; INSERT INTO mysql.rds_heartbeat2(id, value) values (1,1524671965007) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 1524671965007 |
| mysql-bin-changelog.002664 | 391 | Xid         | 1550192458 |         422 | COMMIT /* xid=308462 */                                                                                                         |
| mysql-bin-changelog.002664 | 422 | Rotate      | 1550192458 |         479 | mysql-bin-changelog.002665;pos=4                                                                                                |
+----------------------------+-----+-------------+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Question:**

1. Why was **Debezium idle**? Why didn't it read the files from MySQL after 002640 file?  
   This was not in use by any service. So there couldn't have been a scenario where there were too many writes happening before Debezium could read it.
2. Why did **Amazon MySQL RDS** delete the binlog files, when there was no activity happening? 
   This is a test database and only I insert records in it. So there was no outside application activity happening here.
3. Is there a way to **Resume *Debezium* connector** and start processing records from the time log are currently available at MySQL? (If I'm okay with those unread records being lost).
   I tried restarting the job, deleting and adding the connector but I always end up with the same error. 
   The only solution that worked for resuming the event

   - Delete the Kafka Connect's offet topic.
   - Delete & Add the debezium connector again. 
     I wanted a different approach as in production we'll have a whole lot of connectors which will be using the same offset topic. So deletion would not be possible.

Comment: I have no idea about #1 or #3 but RDS deletes the logs as soon as they are not needed *for anything RDS is aware of* (such as a stalled RDS replica), which typically means within about 5 to 10 minutes under normal conditions.  You can't make RDS aware of an external connector, but can delay this automatic log expiration in 1 hour increments, for a total of up to 7 days: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_configuration.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks. I could use this as a work-around for now. Would increasing this to a day cause any performance issues? I'm planning on changing this configuration anywhere from 1hour-1day depending on how idle the DB could be. Should I be worried if I go ahead with this?

Answer (score 2):

please look at `heartbeat.interval.ms` config property - this should prevent the situations when you have a low traffic table monitored by Debezium in a high-traffic environment. Insuch case it can happen that binlog is flushed but the current binlog coordinates are not recorded in the offsets topic.

Regarding the resume - you can recover from the situation by modifying offsets topic. here you would need to insert an offset record for the plug-in and binlog coordinates that are available on the server. There is a [Kafka KIP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-199%3A+Add+Kafka+Connect+offset+tool) for a tool that would help with this. Now you need to do it manually.

Comment: I tried configuring heartbeat.interval.ms but it still doesn't help. When I've white-listed few tables in connector and no updates happen on these tables, then my offset is not getting incremented in debezium. To resume the process I manually tried to update the offset but it still doesn't help. `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic cdc-offsets` with data `{"file":"mysql-bin-changelog.003188","pos":120,"event":2}`. Which topic should I modify to update the last read binlog filename & offset? The only way it works is if I delete topic cdc-offsets & restart connect.

Comment: What Debezium version do you use?

Comment: I'm using 0.7.5

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: @james.bondu I went ahead with patching the code and handling it in 2 ways. For Scenario's where we're okay with losing this intermediate change, 1) handle this exception and automatically resume from the binlog position which is available in Server. 2) Take a fresh snapshot, remove older records and continue streaming again. Introduced a property while on-boarding a connector to handle these scenarios.

Comment: Offset manipulation has been documented at https://debezium.io/docs/faq/#how_to_change_the_offsets_of_the_source_database

Comment: The previous link doesn't work. The updated link is https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#how_to_change_the_offsets_of_the_source_database